# Jquery load() not loading images

Tags: jquery, load

This code is loading text and css, but not a single image from other PHP pages (tested using xampp)

```
$("ul#nav a").click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#decor").animate({opacity: 0.1,}, 1000 );
    $("#block").hide(700).animate(
        {width: "700px",
        height: "400px",
        opacity: 0.9,},
        200,
        function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(700).load("content/"+ page +".php"); 
        });
    return false;
});
```

Can load() load images and text from another php pages?

Comment: Can you show the output? also check the images' src, it might be wrong.

Comment: What do you mean single image? img tag?

Comment: It dosent load img tags it loads only one image.

Comment: Img src are ok i have tested that when i rename image to represent other image it dosent load it only loads one specific image rest of them dosent

Answer (score 0):

Yes the `load()` function in jquery can load the images , you may have to do something like this.

```
var name='FULL_PATH?dt=' + (+new Date());
$('<img src="'+name+'">').load(function() {
       $('#ID').html('');
       $(this).width('40').height('40').appendTo('#ID');
});
```

This will force the browser to load new image , breaking the cache. 
and cheers :)